# Colocate pacemaker Master resources with stateless resources

Tags: high-availability, pacemaker, corosync

I've implemented a simple two-node cluster with DRBD and a couple of network-based Master/Slave resources.

Using the ethmonitor RA, I set up failover whenever the Master/Primary node loses link on the specified ethernet physical device by constraining the Master role only on nodes where the ethmon variable is "1".

Something is going wrong with my colocation constraint, however - if I set up the DRBDFS resource to monitor link on eth1, unplugging eth1 on the Primary node causes a failover as expected - all Master resources are demoted to "slave" and promoted on the opposite node, and the "normal" DRBDFS moves to the other node as expected.

However, if I put the same ethmonitor constraint on the network-based Master/Slave resource, only that specific resource fails over - DRBDFS stays in the same location (though it stops) as do the other Master/Slave resources.

This *smells* like a constraints issue to me - does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

PCS before:

```
Cluster name: node1.hostname.com_node2.hostname.com
Stack: corosync
Current DC: node2.hostname.com_0 (version 1.1.16-12.el7_4.4-94ff4df) - partition with quorum
Last updated: Tue Mar 20 16:25:47 2018
Last change: Tue Mar 20 16:00:33 2018 by hacluster via crmd on node2.hostname.com_0

2 nodes configured
11 resources configured

Online: [ node1.hostname.com_0 node2.hostname.com_0 ]

Full list of resources:

 Master/Slave Set: drbd.master [drbd.slave]
     Masters: [ node1.hostname.com_0 ]
     Slaves: [ node2.hostname.com_0 ]
 drbdfs (ocf::heartbeat:Filesystem):    Started node1.hostname.com_0
 Master/Slave Set: inside-interface-sameip.master [inside-interface-sameip.slave]
     Masters: [ node1.hostname.com_0 ]
     Slaves: [ node2.hostname.com_0 ]
 Master/Slave Set: outside-interface-sameip.master [outside-interface-sameip.slave]
     Masters: [ node1.hostname.com_0 ]
     Slaves: [ node2.hostname.com_0 ]
 Clone Set: monitor-eth1-clone [monitor-eth1]
     Started: [ node1.hostname.com_0 node2.hostname.com_0 ]
 Clone Set: monitor-eth2-clone [monitor-eth2]
     Started: [ node1.hostname.com_0 node2.hostname.com_0 ]

Daemon Status:
  corosync: active/enabled
  pacemaker: active/enabled
  pcsd: inactive/disabled
```

PCS after:

```
Cluster name: node1.hostname.com_node2.hostname.com
Stack: corosync
Current DC: node2.hostname.com_0 (version 1.1.16-12.el7_4.4-94ff4df) - partition with quorum
Last updated: Tue Mar 20 16:29:40 2018
Last change: Tue Mar 20 16:00:33 2018 by hacluster via crmd on node2.hostname.com_0

2 nodes configured
11 resources configured

Online: [ node1.hostname.com_0 node2.hostname.com_0 ]

Full list of resources:

 Master/Slave Set: drbd.master [drbd.slave]
     Masters: [ node1.hostname.com_0 ]
     Slaves: [ node2.hostname.com_0 ]
 drbdfs (ocf::heartbeat:Filesystem):    Stopped
 Master/Slave Set: inside-interface-sameip.master [inside-interface-sameip.slave]
     Masters: [ node2.hostname.com_0 ]
     Stopped: [ node1.hostname.com_0 ]
 Master/Slave Set: outside-interface-sameip.master [outside-interface-sameip.slave]
     Masters: [ node1.hostname.com_0 ]
     Slaves: [ node2.hostname.com_0 ]
 Clone Set: monitor-eth1-clone [monitor-eth1]
     Started: [ node1.hostname.com_0 node2.hostname.com_0 ]
 Clone Set: monitor-eth2-clone [monitor-eth2]
     Started: [ node1.hostname.com_0 node2.hostname.com_0 ]

Daemon Status:
  corosync: active/enabled
  pacemaker: active/enabled
  pcsd: inactive/disabled
```

This is the "constraints" section of my CIB:

```
<constraints>
    <rsc_colocation id="pcs_rsc_colocation_set_drbdfs_set_drbd.master_inside-interface-sameip.master_outside-interface-sameip.master" score="INFINITY">
        <resource_set id="pcs_rsc_set_drbdfs" sequential="false">
            <resource_ref id="drbdfs"/>
        </resource_set>
        <resource_set id="pcs_rsc_set_drbd.master_inside-interface-sameip.master_outside-interface-sameip.master" role="Master" sequential="false">
            <resource_ref id="drbd.master"/>
            <resource_ref id="inside-interface-sameip.master"/>
            <resource_ref id="outside-interface-sameip.master"/>
        </resource_set>
    </rsc_colocation>
    <rsc_order id="pcs_rsc_order_set_drbd.master_inside-interface-sameip.master_outside-interface-sameip.master_set_drbdfs" kind="Serialize" symmetrical="false">
        <resource_set action="promote" id="pcs_rsc_set_drbd.master_inside-interface-sameip.master_outside-interface-sameip.master-1" role="Master">
            <resource_ref id="drbd.master"/>
            <resource_ref id="inside-interface-sameip.master"/>
            <resource_ref id="outside-interface-sameip.master"/>
        </resource_set>
        <resource_set id="pcs_rsc_set_drbdfs-1">
            <resource_ref id="drbdfs"/>
        </resource_set>
    </rsc_order>
    <rsc_location id="location-inside-interface-sameip.master" rsc="inside-interface-sameip.master">
        <rule id="location-inside-interface-sameip.master-rule" score="-INFINITY">
            <expression attribute="ethmon_result-eth1" id="location-inside-interface-sameip.master-rule-expr" operation="ne" value="1"/>
        </rule>
    </rsc_location>
    <rsc_location id="location-outside-interface-sameip.master" rsc="outside-interface-sameip.master">
        <rule id="location-outside-interface-sameip.master-rule" score="-INFINITY">
            <expression attribute="ethmon_result-eth2" id="location-outside-interface-sameip.master-rule-expr" operation="ne" value="1"/>
        </rule>
    </rsc_location>
</constraints>
```